# Batch Script - IF EXIST copy to %localappdata% error

Tags: windows, batch-file

I seem to be stuck with a batch script and would like some help.

Basically I need to check if a file exists in a folder in the `%localappdata%` and if it does then overwrite the file and if not place inside a different location so at the moment it reads like this:

```
IF EXIST "%localappdata%\foldername\filename" COPY /Y "filename" "location" ELSE COPY "filename" "location2"
```

But when this runs I'm receiving an error of `The syntax of the command is incorrect.`  This seems to be down to the `%localappdata%` variable being used.

Thank you in advance for any help on this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to put the two commands for the `IF` branches in parens:

```
IF EXIST "%localappdata%\foldername\filename" (COPY /Y "filename" "location") ELSE (COPY "filename" "location2")
```

The reason for this is that the shell needs to be able to tell that if the file does exist, the command you want to run is just this:

```
COPY /Y "filename" "location"
```

and *not* all of this:

```
COPY /Y "filename" "location" ELSE COPY "filename" "location2"
```

If you think about it, all those `ELSE COPY` stuff may very well be legitimate parameters for the first `COPY` -- the shell has no way to know unless you help.

Comment: Brilliant Jon.

I knew it'd be something straightforward! That makes total sense.  Thank you very much for your answer.