# Batch copy and overwrite files if they exist in the destination

Tags: windows, batch-file

I found the following batch script here on SE:

[Batch Script - IF EXIST copy to %localappdata% error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6570313/batch-script-if-exist-copy-to-localappdata-error)

```
IF EXIST "%localappdata%\foldername\filename" (COPY /Y "filename" "location")
```

How do I modify the script to operate on a directory full of files? I tried this but it didn't work:

```
IF EXIST "temp\*.*" (COPY /Y "artwork\*.*" "temp")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`xcopy` command includes a *update* switch to only copy files that are already present in the target folder.

```dos
xcopy /y /u "artwork\*" "temp"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like that :

```
@echo off
set "FolderSource=%localappdata%\FolderTest"
Set "Target=%~dp0Location"
IF Not EXIST "%FolderSource%" echo "%FolderSource%" does not exist & pause>nul & exit
If Not Exist "%Target%" MD "%Target%"
For /f "delims=" %%a in ('Dir /b /s "%FolderSource%\*.*"') Do (
    IF EXIST "%Target%\%%a" ( COPY /Y "%%a" "%Target%"
        ) ELSE ( COPY "%%a" "%Target%"
    )
)
pause>nul
```